# Using Jupyter notebook with SparkR

Tags: sparkr, jupyter-irkernel

I want to use `Jupyter` notebook with SparkR, I want to install IR kernel on `Jupyter` which is installed on my `Spark` cluster.

I could find help on using `Jupyter` with `pySpark`, but not with `SparkR`.

I have created my `Spark` cluster on `AWS-EMR` cluster.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not essential to use IRkernel, to use Jupyter with Spark you should consider installing the Apache Toree kernel: https://toree.incubator.apache.org/

This kernel will allow you to connect a Jupyter notebook with Spark using any of the Spark APIs.  It also permits the use of magics (eg %pyspark or %sparkr) to switch between languages in different cells of a single notebook.

Answer (score 0):

After you create a kernel with Toree, your kernel.json should include a SPARK_HOME env, indeed it is something like:

> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2":
>   "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2",

and sometimes:

> "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2": "spark-home",

Despite I fixed the SPARK_HOME manually for Scala and get the Scala kernel working, I am  still not able to get the SparkR kernel working for me, but maybe the bug in the kernel is the first thing you should check - if you are using Toree.